# SQL nested count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, nested

first: yes i'm a sql noob and i really need some help:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(rating), COUNT(rating) FROM comments WHERE phone='$phone';"
```

this needs to be something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(rating), (COUNT(rating) WHERE rating>0) FROM comments WHERE phone='$phone';"
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Why didn't you try adding the required `WHERE` clause to the actual `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: like this: `SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(rating), COUNT(rating) FROM comments WHERE phone='$phone' AND rating > 0;` ??

Comment: maybe he wants the "HAVING" clause with `HAVING COUNT(rating) > 0` ...

Comment: I'm not sure if "HAVING" in your example only depends on rating?

I need count(id) and sum(rating) in very case, but count(rating) only, if the rating is >0.

Comment: Something like this:

`SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(rating), (COUNT(rating) HAVING rating>0) FROM comments WHERE phone='$phone';"`

But how is the correct sql-syntax? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement within the COUNT:-

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(rating), (SUM(CASE WHEN rating > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
FROM comments 
WHERE phone='$phone'";
```

Comment: Hi Kickstart - this results in "Unexpected while". Next line is a while statement: `while($row=mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: Needs a semi colon at the end of the line.

Comment: Can you post the code. There seems nothing wrong with the above line so I would need to see the lines around it.

Comment: Sure, actually it's like this:

`$countresult=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(rating), COUNT(rating) FROM comments WHERE phone='$phone';");
     //$countresult=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(rating), (SUM(CASE rating > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) FROM comments WHERE phone='$phone';")
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($countresult)){ 
     global $count;
     $count=$row[0];
     $ratings=$row[1];
     $sumratings=$row[2];
`

Comment: That should be fine, unless your commented out statement goes over multiple lines (if so the first line of the statement would be commented out but not the rest of it). Just thought of one thing though, the actual SQL statement should not be terminated by a semi colon (but this shouldn't cause the issue you are having).

Comment: If I use your statement
`$countresult=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(rating), (SUM(CASE rating > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) FROM comments WHERE phone='$phone'");`
I get: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Doh. Been a long week. I missed out the WHEN from the case statement. Sorry. Amended answer now.

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want this?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id), 
    SUM(rating), 
    COUNT(rating) 
FROM comments 
WHERE phone='$phone' AND rating > 0
```

If not, please add some explanation to your post.

P.s. I'm guessing you're using PHP. Make sure you don't get caught in the trap that's called MySQL injection

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers: 

MrSoundless: I only want to count ratings, when the count is >0.

Counting / SUM all other values but count rating only if it's >0.